# android- creating a blocking call for run time permission

Tags: android, permissions

The code given [in this tutorial](https://codinginflow.com/tutorials/android/run-time-permission-request) teaches how to obtain run time permissions for dangerous permissions for api level >=23 . But, I've tested this on a few sample projects and it seems to be a nonblocking method for requesting permission i.e.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button buttonRequest = findViewById(R.id.button);
    buttonRequest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You have already granted this permission!", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                requestStoragePermission();
            }
                Log.e("THIS LINE: ", "SEEMS TO BE EXECUTED");
        }
    });
}
```

As I've demonstrated above, the `Log.e` is executed. But, what I want is for the permission request to block until the user decides. How can I do this?
The code for the [requestPermission() method is here](https://codinginflow.com/tutorials/android/run-time-permission-request).

Comment: "But, I've tested this on a few sample projects and it seems to be a nonblocking method for requesting permission" -- correct. The UI for the user to grant or deny the permission is an activity in a system process. "But, what I want is for the permission request to block until the user decides. How can I do this?" -- that is not an option, sorry.

Comment: @CommonsWare , but you see I get the cursor from content resolver and a moveToNext() is triggered right after, and since this is nonblocking, the app crashes. What do you think can be done?

Comment: Move that code elsewhere. Only call that code once you have permission, either because you have permission right now or you received permission and found out about that in the `onRequestPermissionsResult()` callback. See [this sample app](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-java/-/tree/v0.9/ContentEditor) for an example.